# Installing NodeJS and SocketIO in a Remote Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My project is a Real Time Two-Player Facebook Game, and what I need is a tool that will help me build the game with quick responses to enable the "Real Time" function of the game. I have just found out about the Node JS and Socket IO. I have some knowledge in JavaScript so I stepped up and watched a few tutorials that discuss the functions of Node JS and Socket IO.

Here's the link to the videos that I have watched:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSE6xHkcX0w

I understand the basic of the Node JS and Socket IO and successfully installed it in my localhost. The problem is when I uploaded the files from my localhost to my remote server, some functions of the program are not working well. I don't know how to node my JavaScript file when it is on the server, because if it's in my localhost, I am using command prompt to run it.

```
node app.js
```

Comment: What sort of hosting are you using? Most shared hosting providers will not allow you to run Node.js applications.

Comment: I am using a paid Personal Hosting with 1GB Disk Space and 10GB Bandwidth.

Comment: That's still not very specific since many different hosts probably provide a plan named that with different characteristics. Anyway, that does sound like shared hosting, which will not allow you to run Node.js applications. You may need to upgrade to a VPS.

Comment: Whoa. I looked for VPS service from local providers here in my country, and it's very costly. Do I really need to upgrade to VPS? Are there any other ways to run Node.JS in my server?

Comment: You could ask your hosting provider if they can install Node.js for you, but most would probably say no. VPSes are often more costly than plain shared web hosting, but you don't need anything very beefy: I've heard that [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) has fairly affordable VPSes. (A downside is that they need more maintenance on your part, but that's a side effect of more control.)

Answer (score 3):

Node is ***not*** a web framework.

Chances are, you're using a web host that's generalized for web frameworks like PHP and Ruby on Rails. You're going to need virtual private server hosting, or Node-specific hosting, because Node requires a virtual machine to run. You otherwise won't be able to run Node Package Manager or Node itself.

Joyent has provided a list of hosts [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting).

If you chose to use a VPS or dedicated machine, an installation guide would be found [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation). This is how you would install Node on CentOS.

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v<version>/node-v<version>.tar.gz
tar -zxf node-v<version>.tar.gz
cd node-v<version>
./configure
make -j <number of cores>
make install
```